# Web API 2 OData EDM Anomaly

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have the following code:

```
public class AwardTitle
{
    public int AwardTitleId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int? EpisodeId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual AwardEpisode Episode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class AwardEpisode
{
    public int EpisodeId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register( HttpConfiguration config )
    {
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute( "ODataRoute", "api", GetImplicitEDM( ) );
    }
}

private static Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel GetImplicitEDM( )
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder( );
    builder.EntitySet<AwardTitle>( "AwardTitles" );

    return builder.GetEdmModel( );
}
```

Notice how I have only mapped the `AwardTitle` class... not the `AwardEpisode` class.

Now, when I browse to the controller, I would expect to get an error about not having `AwardEpisode` mapped. However, there is no error. In fact, in addition to `AwardTitle` being retrieved... `AwardEpisode` is also being retrieved... without any explicit calls to do so.

How is this possible??? Should this be possible??

I'm using ASP.Net Web API 2 on Windows 7.

Comment: I bet the edm generator uses reflection to reclusively create all dependent classes. Perhaps there is a setting to tell the template generator to ignore a class.

Comment: It is by design this way.

Comment: vitore, I don't think it's by design. Every other time I implement the controller, the dependent classes are not included unless I specifically ask for them using $expand

Answer (score 1):

ODataConventionModelBuilder by default map a type `T`'s primitive, complex, and navigation properties for the `.EntitySet<TEntityType>(string name)` api call. The [code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OData/src/System.Web.Http.OData/OData/Builder/ODataConventionModelBuilder.cs) is:

```
private void MapEntityType(EntityTypeConfiguration entity)
{
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = ConventionsHelpers.GetProperties(entity, includeReadOnly: _isQueryCompositionMode);
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        bool isCollection;
        StructuralTypeConfiguration mappedType;

        PropertyKind propertyKind = GetPropertyType(property, out isCollection, out mappedType);

        if (propertyKind == PropertyKind.Primitive || propertyKind == PropertyKind.Complex)
        {
            MapStructuralProperty(entity, property, propertyKind, isCollection);
        }
        else
        {
            // don't add this property if the user has already added it.
            if (!entity.NavigationProperties.Where(p => p.Name == property.Name).Any())
            {
                NavigationPropertyConfiguration addedNavigationProperty;
                if (!isCollection)
                {
                    addedNavigationProperty = entity.AddNavigationProperty(property, EdmMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne);
                }
                else
                {
                    addedNavigationProperty = entity.AddNavigationProperty(property, EdmMultiplicity.Many);
                }

                addedNavigationProperty.AddedExplicitly = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

An [example](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OData/test/System.Web.Http.OData.Test/OData/Builder/Conventions/ODataConventionModelBuilderTests.cs) of the test case:

```
public void ModelBuilder_Products()
{
    var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");

    var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();

    var product = model.AssertHasEntitySet(entitySetName: "Products", mappedEntityClrType: typeof(Product));
    product.AssertHasPrimitiveProperty(model, "ReleaseDate", EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.DateTime, isNullable: true);
    product.AssertHasComplexProperty(model, "Version", typeof(ProductVersion), isNullable: true);
    product.AssertHasNavigationProperty(model, "Category", typeof(Category), isNullable: true, multiplicity: EdmMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne);
```

To change the default behavior, we can ignore the property:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.Entity<AwardTitle>().Ignore(a => a.Episode);
builder.EntitySet<AwardTitle>("AwardTitles");

return builder.GetEdmModel();
```